# Sandbox: can I get an html list item to Run in iframe?

Tags: sandbox-solution, iframe, response

I guess the real question is can I get rid of these lines in Response Header:

> X-Download-Options: noopen

and

> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...

so I can actually see an HTML page run inside iFrame?
As you will see in my code I got anonymous access and browserFileHandling, but still, the browser only offers the file for download...

```
  public void setPermissions(String listName, SPWeb web)
    {           
        try
        {                          
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            web.Update();               
            SPList list = web.Lists[listName];  
            list.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
            list.Update(); 
            list.AnonymousPermMask64 =
                (SPBasePermissions.Open |
                SPBasePermissions.UseClientIntegration |
                SPBasePermissions.OpenItems |
                SPBasePermissions.EditListItems |
                SPBasePermissions.ViewFormPages |
                SPBasePermissions.ViewPages |
                SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems |
                SPBasePermissions.BrowseDirectories |                    
                SPBasePermissions.BrowseUserInfo |
                SPBasePermissions.UseRemoteAPIs );
            list.BrowserFileHandling = SPBrowserFileHandling.Permissive;
            list.DefaultItemOpen = DefaultItemOpen.Browser;
            list.Update();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            web.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //...
        }                
    }
```

When I use Fiddler and filter the Response Header it works great... Help!

Answer (score 0):

Wrote on the same issue a while ago:

http://vrdmn.blogspot.in/2012/06/use-html-pages-in-sharepoint-2010-html.html

> Quick and Dirty Hack:  You can keep the extension of a file as .aspx
>   and include pure html inside it and SharePoint will run it even if the
>   Browser File Handling is set to "Strict

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I was aware of this hack but the case here is that there will be A LOT of html files and I am looking for a more automated solution. Could I use this trick an a programmatic fashion?